# looking for a month/year selector control for .net winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am looking for a month selector control for a .net 2 winform.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use [`DateTimePicker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx). You can use a [custom format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx) to enable just the month and year to be specified.

Example:

```
DateTimePicker dateTimePicker1 = new DateTimePicker();
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MM yyyy";
dateTimePicker1.ShowUpDown = true; // to prevent the calendar from being displayed
```

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2ef6zxz.aspx) for more information.

**Edit:**
To prevent the calendar from being displayed, set the `ShowUpDown` property on the `DateTimePicker` to `true`. This will prevent the calendar from being displayed and (in conjunction with a `CustomFormat`) allow you to set just the month and year by using the up/down buttons.

Comment: any way to disable the day selection and just show the month and year?

Comment: How can I pick month and year value ?