# How to set Datetimepicker to Month and Year only format?

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

How can I set the `Datetimepicker`-Format to MM/YYYY?

Comment: View the answer and take a look at here too; http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm

Comment: possible duplicate of [looking for a month/year selector control for .net winform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608792/looking-for-a-month-year-selector-control-for-net-winform)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use `DateTimerPicker.Format` property. Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.format.aspx)

```
public void SetMyCustomFormat()
{
   // Set the Format type and the CustomFormat string.
   dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
   dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MM/yyyy";
}
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use `DateTimerPicker.Format` property as following:

```
DateTimerPicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
DateTimerPicker.CustomFormat = "MMMM yyyy";
DateTimerPicker.ShowUpDown = true;
```

Note: `DateTimerPicker.ShowUpDown = true;` is for making the calendar not visible

Answer (score 5):

This will give you some more options to display date with diff formats.

```
DateTimerPicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
DateTimerPicker.CustomFormat = "MM/yyyy"; // this line gives you only the month and year.
DateTimerPicker.ShowUpDown = true;
```

Below are the different formats to display date alone on the date time picker control of the Windows applciation C#

```
DateTimerPicker.CustomFormat = "MMMM yyyy";
```

The above code will display the full month name and year like "August 2018"

```
DateTimerPicker.CustomFormat = "MMMM yyyy";
```

The above code will display the full month name, date and year like "08 August 2018"

```
DateTimerPicker.CustomFormat = "dd MM yyyy";
```

This line will give the date in the specified format with out forward slash "08 08 2018"

```
DateTimerPicker.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
```

This line will give more specific format to the date "08/08/2018"

```
DateTimerPicker.CustomFormat = "dd/MMM/yyyy";
```

This line give date in the format of "08/Aug/2018"

Answer (score -3):

This line worked for me

`DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MMMM dd yyyy")`

output: August 2019