# ASP DateTimeControl with months and years only

Tags: asp.net, date, user-controls, controls, aspx-user-control

In Windows you can display the Calendar in (MMMM yyyy) format.

I would like my `<asp:DateTimeControl>` to do the same.

I found the DateOnly property to remove the hour/min/sec from the Date, but how can I make this control pick only months in the year ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Datetimepicker to Month and Year only format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137022/how-to-set-datetimepicker-to-month-and-year-only-format)

Comment: Datetimepicker isn't an ASP control, is it ? How i use a DateTimepicker with this asp control ?