# C# Hide day when selecting DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm trying to create a month picker using the 'DateTimePicker' of C#:

[image]

The problem is, is that the datetimepicker shows the day too.

Is there a way I can 'hide' the days in the form and only show months and years?

Comment: Won't it be better to have 2 dropdowns (month and year) or 1 dropdown having month-Year (Nov-2018, Dec-2018 ...)?

Comment: i'm trying to evade that because then I don't know how many years i should implement in the dropdown of `year`

Comment: @AmrElgarhy it's not a duplicate because i don't want to change the format of the date it returns, i want to HIDE the day on the form

Comment: does this change the format of the date it return? I didn't test it but I assume it will return the full datetime and not a string of just month/year. I think this property in the question I sent is just a display property.

Comment: If not dopdown for year, you can have a number textbox with limit of 4 digits?

Comment: @AmrElgarhy yes it does, it does not hide the day ON the form itself, please remove the 'possible duplicate'

Comment: check this as well if it help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1608804/20126

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `Format` and `CustomFormat` properties on the `DateTimePicker` to customize the display. To show the full month name, use `MMMM` and for the 4-character year use `yyyy`.

You can find out more about custom `DateTime` format strings [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

```
DateTimePicker dateTimePicker1 = new DateTimePicker
{
    Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom,
    CustomFormat = "MMMM yyyy",
    ShowUpDown = true
};

Controls.Add(dateTimePicker1);
```

Output:

[image: ![![enter image description here]